# Swift - How to hide a label then after a button is pressed make it show forever?

Tags: swift, uibutton, uilabel

I am trying to have the label start off hidden, then after a button is pressed have the label show forever even after you log out/restart the app. Right now it shows after I click the button but becomes hidden after I log out/restart. Here is my code:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
    hidePercent()
}

var didTapOptionsButtonForCell: ((YourPollsCell) -> Void)?

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state

    let percentColor = UIColor(red: 115/255, green: 21/255, blue: 54/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    pollText1Percent.layer.borderColor = percentColor
    pollText1Percent.layer.borderWidth = 2
    pollText2Percent.layer.borderColor = percentColor
    pollText2Percent.layer.borderWidth = 2
}

func hidePercent() {
    pollText1Percent.isHidden = true
    pollText2Percent.isHidden = true
}

@IBAction func reportButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    didTapOptionsButtonForCell?(self)
}

@IBAction func pollText1ButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.didTapVoteButton(sender, pollNum: 1, on: self)

    pollText1Percent.isHidden = false
    pollText2Percent.isHidden = false
}

@IBAction func pollText2ButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    delegate?.didTapVoteButton(sender, pollNum: 2, on: self)

    pollText1Percent.isHidden = false
    pollText2Percent.isHidden = false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add a value to the UserDefaults when button is tapped.

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(value: true, forKey: "specialButtonWasTapped")
```

Then check this value in controller when app is launched and set isHidden property.

```
if let wasTapped = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "specialButtonWasTapped") {
    specialLabel.isHidden = !wasTapped    // false
}
else {
    specialLabel.isHidden = true
}
```

Or to clean up that idea

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(value: false, forKey: "labelShouldBeHidden")
```

Then you could just set the isHidden property with the nil coalescing operator

```
specialLabel.isHidden = (UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "labelShouldBeHidden") as? Bool) ?? true
```